# Define a function reference so that it retains its argument names

Tags: scala

Is there a way in scala to define a function *prototype* so that it has argument names like a regular function? For example, I have a factory that I can represent as a single function trait like this:

```
trait FactoryTrait {
  def build(factory: ActorRefFactory, id: Int, creator: ActorRef): ActorRef
}
```

If I pass this as an argument to a class and call it, inspection of the type can tell me not only that `build` takes three arguments and their types, but also the descriptive names. But I have to pass and instance of the factory and call `factory.build(actorRefFactory, id, creator)` rather than just a simple function.

If on the other hand I define the factory as a type such as:

```
type FactoryDef = (ActorRefFactory, Int, ActorRef) => ActorRef
```

I can pass the function reference directly as an arg, I can call `factory(actorRefFactory, id, creator)` but inspection of `factory` lacks the descriptive argument naming, for example, IntelliJ just calls them `v1, v2, v3`. While this seems a trivial complaint, when factories take multiple `ActorRef`s the signature becomes unreadable pretty quickly.

Is there an alternate way of defining a function reference that does retain the argument names?

Comment: Can you give a few more details about your use case? `type FactoryDef = (ActorRefFactory, Int, ActorRef) => ActorRef` smacks a bit of exposing actor internals through closure, which might not be a good idea.

Comment: The use case is an actor that creates child actors, the creation of which I don't want to hardcode. The reason I inject a `factory` instead of a `props` function -- other than it has the same signature issues -- is that with `props` I can't substitute a `TestProbe` for the created child

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not. But you can

1. call the method `apply` instead of `build`. This allows you to write just `factory(actorRefFactory, id, creator)`.
2. add a conversion from functions to the factory trait (possibly implicit):

   ```
   object FactoryTrait {
     def apply(f: (ActorRefFactory, Int, ActorRef) => ActorRef) = new FactoryTrait {
       def apply(factory: ActorRefFactory, id: Int, creator: ActorRef): ActorRef =
         f(factory, id, creator)
     }
   }

   val factory = FactoryTrait { (factory, id, creator) => ... }

   factory(f, i, c)
   ```

Comment: I don't know how I managed to forget about `apply`. That's exactly what I wanted and what's it is made for. Thanks!